# After loading images on scroll image gets disappeared react native

Tags: android, image, react-native, react-native-listview

I have used ListView component from react-native and used it for rendering product details and images.

Now , after the images being loaded I am scrolling the view downwards. While coming back to previous products only images get disappeared and seems to get loaded again from the source.

The image source is a URL.

**Please tell how can I persist the images already loaded in current react Native android screen.**

I am using :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.2.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  },
```

**Updated Code for reference:**

```
     <ListView
         renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         pageSize={data.length}/>    
     </View>

_renderRow(data){
    return (
            <View style={styles.boxContainer}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.image}
                    resizeMode={'contain'}
                    source={{uri: "https://vesyl.in/"+data.image_url}}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

The response from API:

```
data = [];
  for(let i=0; i<responseJson.data.length; i++){
     var t = responseJson.data;
     data.push(t[i]);
  }

const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2)=>r1!==r2});
this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data)});
```

**data.image_url are objects containing image urls.**

Comment: Since you're using RN 0.45, I would recommend using FlatList instead of ListView. Besides that, I really need to see your code in order to help you further.

Comment: @dejakob check the codes please

Comment: Could you add console.log in _renderRow and check if it gets re-rendered?

Comment: what u want check in console? I am getting the images properly, the thing is it is not getting persisted if I scroll back to top.

Comment: Have you checked to see if this is a caching issue by using something like the `cache` prop (iOS only) in your `Image` component or with a package like [react-native-img-cache](https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-img-cache)?

Comment: its for android

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:largeHeap="true"` under `<application>` in your androidManifest file.
Also, add the property `removeClippedSubviews={true}` to your `scrollView`s.